# Trouble installing PDFlib on ubuntu 14.04 PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 (64 bit server)

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

I wonder if anyone has successfully installed pdflib on ubutu 14.04?

From the instructions at http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/support/PDFlib-in-PHP-HowTo.pdf it seems that it ought to be simple but I am having no success with it. What I have done is the following:

1) Uploaded and decompressed PDFlib-9.0.4-Linux-php.tar.gz

2) I have copied  /bind/php/php-550/php_pdflib.so into /usr/lib/php5/20121212. (/usr/lib/php5/20121212 is what phpinfo indicates my extension_dir is)

3) I have modified php.ini with the directive extenstion=php_pdflib.so

4) Restarted Apache.

According to the instructions at this point phpinfo should respond with PDFlib GmbH Binary Version

However there is no indication of anything related to pdf in the phpinfo response.

Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably a typo in posting but it should be `extension=` not `extenstion=`

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, it was a typo.  It is spelled correctly in the php.ini file.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Uploaded and decompressed PDFlib-9.0.4-Linux-php.tar.gz

you loaded the wrong PDFlib Linux package. When you have a 64-bit PHP, you have to use the 64-bit version for PDFlib on Linux. So please choose the PHP package for Linux Intel 64: (PDFlib-9.0.4-Linux-x86_64-php.tar.gz)
http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-9/
please simple replace the DSO and restart your apache once again.